# Toggle vertices/edge/faces with numpad emulation

Tags: modeling

I want to toggle vertex/edge/faces but I can't seem to make keys 1, 2, 3 or Ctrl+ Tab to work on Numpad emulation mode while on a laptop keyboard. Is there any way to remap these?

Blender 2.8
OSX 10.13.6

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I did it this way: go to *Preferences* > *Keymap* > *3D view* > *Mesh* > *Mesh (Global)* > *Select Mod*e, if you unfold the 3 first ones you should see *Type* > *Vertices*, *Type* > *Edges* and *Type* > Faces, and for example, for each one, you could choose <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> / <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> / <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, that was the place to find them. I was searching the title "Vertex Select" in the Keymap but it didn't result in anything. Is this also written in the documentation?

Comment: is what written in the documentation? The Blender documentation is hard to understand actually   ;)

Comment: I mean the place to find them in the preferences and map them to other arbitrary keys. I searched a lot couldn't see them. But thanks that worked!

Comment: I found them because I checked all the settings in the preferences, and I chose these keys because they were available, that's all I can say, plus 2.8 is still a bit foggy for me